# ML Algorithm for Online Sequence Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am writing a program to classify API call sequences at runtime. At the moment I am using pytorch as my ML framework.

Initially I thought this could be accomplished with an LSTM network, but from reading [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html), it seems like LSTMs expect the sequence length to be fixed.

My ideal solution would be able to process a sequence of unknown length incrementally, a single item at a time and compute a label for the sequence up until that point.

Are there machine learning algorithms that can do this?

Comment: You could zero-pad, or make sliding windows.  There are other options too.

Comment: Sliding Windows or zero-padded sequences would mean that i would have to perform inference on the entire sequence each time. That seems like it would slow the application down significantly.

Comment: They use LSTM's in images, where you have hundreds or thousands of paired in parallel.  How fast do you need it? https://jasdeep06.github.io/posts/Understanding-LSTM-in-Tensorflow-MNIST/

Comment: Just to make sure: By classification you mean that you have a finite number of classes + some labeled training data. You expect your classifier to output the correct label for an input it has not seen before, and all inputs have different size is bytes. Is this correct? This task may be difficult because for a problem of varying size it may be difficult to obtain a representative training set. Is it feasible to manually write a function that compresses all inputs to have the same size?

Comment: Pretty fast, I was aiming for less than 1ms per invocation. Its a research project so there are no fixed goals right now.

Comment: For training data, I can generate input sequences of an arbitrary length. The system will be used for malware detection, so I have benign API call sequences and attack sequences that I can mix into those. The training data will have one of three labels for every step in the sequence.